# 'Watching` localStorage for a change

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, computed-properties

I have a vue app which has a feature than can change the theme, for example, `light/dark`,

Initially, I've set in my `localStorage.setItem['app_theme', 'light']`,

I have my app theme changer function in the `Header.vue` component, and after clicking the theme changer toggle button, it also changes the `localStorage['app_theme'] = 'dark'`.

Now, in my other components, I have some `computed values/variables/properties` like this:

```
...
computed() {
    app_card() {
        return localStorage.getItem('app_theme') === 'dark' ? 'card-dark' : 'card-light'; //these are some classes with their respective theme css
    },
    app_text() {
        return localStorage.getItem('app_theme') === 'dark' ? 'text-dark' : 'text-light'; //these are some classes with their respective theme css
    }
}
...
```

I've thought about using polling to get the `localStorage.getItem('app_theme')` value every 2 secs, but I  think this'll slow down my app.

Are there any other alternatives to listen for localstorage item change without polling?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the observer pattern is for.
You create an event "OnAppThemeChange". You can subscribe to that event with all your components.
Then whenever your App Theme changed you call your event, and all the components will refresh their App Theme.

This removes the need of Refreshing the theme every 2 seconds. It will only refresh when you actually change the theme.

Usefull links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events
https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer

Comment: I am not familiar with vue.js, but observer pattern can be implemented in any language.

Comment: I'm new to vanillajs, but I'll try this one. Would be better if you provide a sample code :)

Comment: While this works too. I think its better to stick with Vue's standard methods and use `vuex`  instead.